# About real analytic functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is analytic at 0, i.e., it is given by its Taylor series on a neighborhood $U$ of  0. Then is it necessarily true that $f$ is analytic at every point in $U$ ?

Comment: Yes.  You can find a proof of this fact in Chapter 8 of Baby Rudin ("Principles of Mathematical Analysis").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is true.  The way I'm used to thinking of it is by extending the function to the complex plane, where to show that a function is analytic it suffices to show it is differentiable.  If the power series of $f$ at $0$ has radius of convergence $r$, then this power series can be used to extend $f$ to the open disk of radius $r$ centered at $0$.  Because power series are differentiable and complex differentiable functions are analytic, $f$ will be complex analytic on that disk, and therefore its restriction to the real line will be real analytic.

If you want to stick to real variables, see Chapter 1 of *[A primer of real analytic functions](http://books.google.com/books?id=i4vw2STJl2QC&dq)* by Krantz and Parks (Corollary 1.2.4).

Edit: Thanks to Jesse Madnick for pointing out in a comment that it's also Theorem 8.4 in *[Principles of mathematical analysis](http://books.google.com/books?id=XzFJewAACAAJ&dq)*, 3rd Ed. by Rudin.